# Binding click event with multiple css style in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, binding, event-handling

How do I bind **multiple css class** to the click **event** of Submit button in Angular? On the button submit , the style is suppose to change.

HTML

```
<div class="mainbody" [ngClass]="getStyle">
    <button (click)="getStyle= !getStyle">Submit</button>
</div>
```

TypeScript

```
export class AppComponent {
  style1: boolean = true;
  style2: boolean = true;
}

getStyle()
```

Comment: There are multiple ways. 1 way is to get the `ElementRef` of the button and add your classes into the `classlist`.

Comment: @Rana_S thanks, can you please elaborate as I am new to this .

Comment: I have solved it using [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define two different state objects :

```
export class AppComponent {
  baseState = {
    style1: true,
    style2: true
  }
  activeState = {
    style1: false,
    style2: false
  }
  active = false;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="mainbody" [ngClass]="active ? activeState : baseState">
  <button (click)="active = !active">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sz2013 No problems ;)

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you want to apply a different style if **getStyle** is true or false.

You can do it like this:

```
<div class="mainbody" [ngClass]="{'class_1': getStyle, 'class_2': !getStyle}">
  <button (click)="getStyle = !getStyle">Submit</button>
</div>
```